# watson conversation service dialog node editor doesn't allow context setting

Tags: watson-conversation

In the Watson Conversation Service documentation says, ***"You can store information by modifying the context part of the dialog node definition in an editor. To open the editor, select the node menu and select Advanced".***

However, when I try modifying the dialog node per the example given in the documentation it seems that the dialog service deletes the context setting that I added.

Here's the example in the doc:

```
"context":
{
  "my_dessert_string": "ice-cream",  
  "toppings_array": ["onion", "olives"],
  "age_number": 18,
  "complex_object": {
     "user_firstname" : "Peter",
     "user_lastname" : "Pan",
     "has_card" : false    
   }
}
```

I go into the "advanced response" dialog node editor and add the above to the node, but after I "try it out" it's not there anymore.

What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way to set context variables in a dialog node with Watson Conversation Service?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I missed a "," between the "output" and "context" sections.  When I added the "," it worked fine.

I also found out that the editor flagged this as an error for me by changing the color of the box from blue to red, which is a nice feature to let you know if you still have errors in your dialog node.

Comment: Quite a common issue.